# writecharacteristic android not working with byte array

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with byte arrays and strings.my BLE not wrtie value to the firmware.i am sending bytE Array to write value. there are show the my code as below :-

```
  private boolean writeCharacteristic(String password,String title){
            Log.w("writing log",title);
            if (mGatt == null) {
                Log.e("Connection status", "lost connection");
                return false;
            }
            BluetoothGattService Service = mGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("f9519c06-99ab-4277-83d8-d934fff00000"));
            if (Service == null) {
                Log.e("Service status", "service not found!");
                return false;
            }
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("f9519c06-99ab-4277-83d8-d934fff10000"));
            boolean status ;
            byte[] read=charac.getValue();
            for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                char[] x = password.toCharArray();
                String hex= String.format("%s3", x[i]);
                Integer resuInteger=Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
                read[i+4]=resuInteger.byteValue();
            }
            try {
                charac.setValue(URLEncoder.encode(Arrays.toString(read), "utf-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            charac.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
            status = mGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac);
            mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(charac,true);
            Log.w("status",String.valueOf(status));
            dialog_change.dismiss();
            return status;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change write type to defuault

I use the No response to cysmart
Psoc always can't read
When I use other type it can read my write

So you can try change type